# Modifying tables interactively with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, xlconnect

I am trying to create an interface where I can interactively modify column values of a given source csv permanently. It must function somewhat like MS excel - the entire table displays and I can change column values on the fly and the resulting modifications reflect in the source csv saved in a specific server directory. I was wondering if R shiny can do this. I have experience in creating fluid/reactive pages and manipulating display (column display,check boxes,sliders, filtering etc.) but I have no clue as to how the source data itself can be modified using the Shiny GUI. Can someone please provide some direction? What package (if available) is needed etc. I have full write access on the source csv so credentials are not a problem.

Once I have some traction I plan to expand the operations onto a database.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can look into the `rhandsontable` package.

Comment: Thanks NicE - will do